# Case Insensitive Naming Conventions

Tags: fortran, naming-conventions

Completely apart from the discussions about whether programming languages should be case sensitive or not [[1]](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-case-for-case-insensitivity/) [[2]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9965/why-is-there-still-case-sensitivity-in-some-programming-languages), what would be a good naming convention for languages that are case-insensitive?

Specifically I'm working in Fortran, but most commonly available style guides are for languages that are case sensitive, and thus recommend naming conventions like:

- Class/Type names are `CapitalizedWords`
- Method/function names are `firstWordNotCapitalized`
- Variables are `lower_case_with_underscores`
- Constants are `ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES`

But in case insensitive languages, everything is effectively ALL CAPS, so the only way to legibly have multi-word names is `ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES`. So is my only option for distinguishing between the "kinds" of names to go back to Hungarian Notation?

- Class/Type names are `APPENDED_WITH_T`
- Method/function/subroutine names are `APPENDED_WITH_{F or S}`
- Module names are `APPENDED_WITH_M`
- Variable names are `NOT_APPENDED` (and constants are just variables)

Name collisions are a major problem in Fortran, since even the name of a module will cause a collision with a variable name, or a derived type name. Is this a case where, even though everyone says Hungarian notation is a bad idea, it makes sense in this instance?

Edit:

As a response to a comment, for example, in a case sensitive language (C++ for example) I'd be able to do something like this:

in a file (i.e. module) called `Logger.cc`:

```cpp
class Logger {
    Logger(some type, of arguments) {...}
    log(some argument) {...}
}
```

in another file somewhere:

```cpp
#include "Logger.h"
void aFunctionThatCreatesALogger() {
    ...
    Logger logger = new Logger(with, arguments)
    ...
}

void functionThatLogs(Logger logger) {
    ...
    logger.log(thing)
    ...
}
```

And the equivalent Fortran might look like:

in a file (i.e. module name Logger.f90):

```fortran
module Logger

type Logger
contains
    procedure :: log
end type

contains

type(Logger) function Logger(some, arguments) result(logger)
logger%some = some
logger%arguments = arguments
end function Logger

subroutine log(logger, argument)
class(Logger) :: logger
type(some), intent(in) :: argument
...
end subroutine log

end module Logger
```

in another file somewhere:

```fortran
module someModule

use Logger, only: Logger, Logger

contains

subroutine routineThatCreatesALogger()
type(Logger) :: logger
...
logger = Logger(with, arguments)
...
end subroutine routineThatCreatesALogger

subroutine routineThatLogs(logger)
type(Logger), intent(in) :: logger
...
call logger%log(thing)
...
end subroutine routineThatLogs

end module someModule
```

but of course the name collisions between the module name, the type name, the "constructor" function, and my variable name are all a problem, because Fortran can't tell the difference between case and/or context of use.

I fully understand that any suggestions will be highly subjective, but I'd still like to here if anybody has a better/different suggestion than Hungarian notation.

Comment: *Name collisions are a major problem in Fortran*  Can't say I agree with that.  Can't say that I see this question as inviting anything more solid than opinions in reply.  My own opinion is that this is a non-issue and that Hungarian notation is, therefore, a non-solution.

Comment: Be a REAL FORTRAN programmer -- 6 characters, ALL CAPS! :D

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Really? You've never wanted to name a module the same as the derived type it defines? You've never wanted to name a dummy argument the same as it's type? You've never wanted to name a function the same as it's return type? Maybe it's just me trying to apply patterns that don't make sense in Fortran.

Comment: Here is a convention I sometimes apply for a module describing a unique type "foo" and all associated procedures : the module name is foo_m and the derived type name is foo_t. About procedure names or argument names, I have no specific rule except for an argumentof ty pe foo_t : the normal name is foo.

Comment: Naming a dummy argument or a function after its type strikes me as an odd idea, and I don't believe it has ever crossed my mind.  As for naming a module the same as the derived type it defines, that seems to pre-suppose an approximately 1:1 relationship between modules and derived types.  I may have been tempted occasionally but I've never had a problem in resisting the temptation.  Maybe it is, indeed, just you.  But if it is important to you then don't let my (mal-)practices impede you.

Comment: @SteveLionel, Maybe I'm mis-remembering trying this at one point, but I'm pretty sure a statement like `USE FOO, ONLY: FOO` will cause the compiler to yell at you. And type, variable and function/subroutine names don't have separate namespaces. As an example, imagine I was trying to explicitly import a variable, type and function with the same names from a module. What would that statement look like? `USE FOO, ONLY: FOO, FOO, FOO` Which FOO refers to which of the variable type or function? Since the compiler won't be able to tell, it's clearly not valid.

Comment: There are so many conventions in the wild that there is clearly no widely agreed-upon solution. It is very opinion-based. The important thing to always make consistent conventions within a project. Do not bring any "better" novelties into an existing project, if you don't want to rename all existing stuff.

Comment: @Brad Richardson Mea culpa. I should have known better...  Module names are global names. Variable names and derived type names are local names of the same class. You're not allowed to have a local name be the same as a global name, with some exceptions (such as the rename-name in a USE. Nevertheless, naming conventions are straightforward and should not rely on case.

Comment: I personally use prefixes (`mmodule`, `ddouble`, `llogical`, etc). I find case-sensitivity annoying, but I guess this really comes down to personal preference. I would find it distracting if things had the same name apart from capitalizing.

Comment: My convention is essentially the same as @FrancoisJacq above, that is, foo_t for type names, foo_m (or foo_mod) for module names, and no suffix for other things (variables and procedures). Btw, I guess "Hungarian notation" refers (usually?) to more extensive naming schemes (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation ). As for procedures, some people seem to like start them with verbs and use nouns for variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the major reason for the case variations in naming conventions is to give a hint to the **human reader** as to what that name denotes, not to avoid name clashes.

So unless your compiler *really*  supports only uppercase names, for the most part you can adopt the usual conventions even in case-insensitive languages.

---

If name clashing really begins to be a problem, using prefixes or suffixes (the latter are most likely preferable) might be ok, but I wouldn't make it a general, compulsory convention, but just a thing to use when it's needed.
And (especially) if you do indeed use them only occasionaly, it's most likely better to use something self-explanatory rather than single letters or strange acronyms.

---

Your examples `aFunctionThatCreatesALogger` or `functionThatLogs`, if they were meant as name proposals, might actually not be the monstrosity that they seem at first glance (if used occasionally), but I'd argue that it's much better to start with the most relevant term (log), and put the eventual specifiers at the end (e.g. `loggerCreatingFunction` or `loggerFunction`).

Whether to use a full, expanded term, an abbreviation/acronym or even a single letter should depend mostly on whether most developers use tools with good auto-completion or not.

But you should always be wary to use these specifiers, it's most likely better to avoid things like that as much as possible.
So if you wrote code which declares names that use them, think thrice before committing it.

---

Note that I don't know Fortran (but I did work a lot with another case-insensitive language).

Comment: using case conventions in a case-insensitive language would seem to invite problems as you may inadvertently use symbols that differ only in case.

Comment: I don't see how that would be a bigger problem in case-insensitve languages than in case-sensitive ones...

Comment: *I'm pretty sure that the major reason for the case variations in naming conventions is to give a hint to the human reader as to what that name denotes, not to avoid name clashes.*  I'm pretty sure that all aspects of almost all naming conventions are to give hints to humans as to what a name denotes.  Unless you are programming in one of those (now rare) languages which infers an entity's type from its name.  As Fortran does (or at least, can do).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I'm going to stick with my initial idea. Append `_t` to type names, and in situations where a module contains something with the same name, append `_module` to module names. Other than that I'll stick with the common convention:

- Class/Type names are CapitalizedWords
- Method/function names are firstWordNotCapitalized
- Variables are lower_case_with_underscores
- Constants are ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES

That should avoid the vast majority of naming collisions and (hopefully) produce readable code.

The above Fortran example would then become:

```fortran
module Logger_module

type Logger_t
contains
    procedure :: log
end type

contains

type(Logger_t) function createLogger(some, arguments) result(logger)
logger%some = some
logger%arguments = arguments
end function createLogger

subroutine log(logger, argument)
class(Logger_t) :: logger
type(some_t), intent(in) :: argument
...
end subroutine log

end module Logger
```

and

```fortran
module some_module

use Logger_module, only: Logger_t, createLogger

contains

subroutine routineThatCreatesALogger()
type(Logger_t) :: logger
...
logger = createLogger(with, arguments)
...
end subroutine routineThatCreatesALogger

subroutine routineThatLogs(logger)
type(Logger_t), intent(in) :: logger
...
call logger%log(thing)
...
end subroutine routineThatLogs

end module some_module
```

Of course this ignores the question as to whether you should use a convention that relies on case in a case insensitive language, but that's the kind of question that *really* invites opinionated and subjective arguments, so I won't ask it.

Comment: *Of course this ignores ..., so I won't ask it.*  You won't be surprised to learn that I disagree with this statement.  There are sufficient examples to be found here on SO where people have written code which fails to recognise that, say `N` and `n`, refer to the same variable in Fortran, that I think it is not (too) opinionated to say that using case-sensitive conventions in a case-insensitive language is a bad practice.

Comment: If you're writing code with single letter variable names, you've probably got more problems than just case-sensitivity and naming conventions. If you've got a better suggestion than what I've outlined above, I'd love to hear it.